# Uploading multiple apps using fastlane iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-gym

I have an Xcode project that is used to build multiple apps. I use the same code with a different bundle ID with its own app in the app store connect.

I have used Jenkins and Fast Lane to achieve CI/CD for this project. I have created a Jenkinsfile with a pipeline script that provides the details and the bundle identifier for the multiple apps. When I try the Jenkins job it works correctly for the first app whose bundle identifier is the same as the one provided in the build setting of the Xcode project. So when Jenkins runs the details of the second app, the archive fails stating “No provisioning profile found”. The provisioning profile and everything were correctly fetched but failed during the build. I’m guessing the issue is with Jenkins archiving the Xcode project build using the bundle ID mentioned in the build settings which is the bundle ID of the first app.  How do I resolve this issue? I was not able to find a way to change the bundle ID and the corresponding provisioning profile during the build (from Xcode build settings). Is there a way to upload multiple apps using the same Jenkins job and fast lane pipeline?

Currently, the details are passed to build settings using an xcconfig file which has details of the apps I'm building with this xcode project.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Jenkinsfile Script:

```
pipeline {
agent any

environment {
    LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    LANGUAGE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    // Other environment variables as needed
}

stages {
    stage('Build and Deploy') {
        steps {
            script {
                // Define shop-specific information for all the shops
                def shopInfo = [
                    [
                        shopName: 'shopName',
                        shopDomain: 'shopDomain',
                        shopifyApiKey: 'shopifyApiKey',
                        shopifyStoreToken: 'shopifyStoreToken',
                        bundleIdentifier: 'bundleIdentifier'
                    ],
                    [
                        shopName: 'shopName',
                        shopDomain: 'shopDomain',
                        shopifyApiKey: 'shopifyApiKey',
                        shopifyStoreToken: 'shopifyStoreToken',
                        bundleIdentifier: 'bundleIdentifier'
                    ]
                    // Add information for other shops here
                ]

                def infoPlistPath = ‘path to Info.plist'  // Update with the correct path

                // Retrieve the Fastlane username and password from Jenkins credentials
                def fastlaneUser = ''
                def fastlanePassword = ''

                // Iterate through the shop information
                for (shop in shopInfo) {
                    // Set shop-specific details
                    def shopName = shop.shopName
                    def shopDomain = shop.shopDomain
                    def shopifyApiKey = shop.shopifyApiKey
                    def shopifyStoreToken = shop.shopifyStoreToken
                    def bundleIdentifier = shop.bundleIdentifier

                    // Set shop-specific environment variables including the bundle identifier
                    withEnv([
                        "SHOP_NAME=${shopName}",
                        "SHOP_DOMAIN=${shopDomain}",
                        "SHOPIFY_API_KEY=${shopifyApiKey}",
                        "SHOPIFY_STORE_TOKEN=${shopifyStoreToken}",
                        "BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=${bundleIdentifier}",
                        'FASTLANE_USER=username,
                        'FASTLANE_PASSWORD=password’
                    ]) {
                        // Change the working directory to the Fastlane directory
                        dir('/Users/shahnasek/Documents/Work/beCo-Store-iOS/beCo-Store/fastlane') {
                            // Run commands to modify Info.plist
                            sh "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :ShopName $SHOP_NAME' $infoPlistPath"
                            sh "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :ShopDomain $SHOP_DOMAIN' $infoPlistPath"
                            sh "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :ShopifyAPIKey $SHOPIFY_API_KEY' $infoPlistPath"
                            sh "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :StoreToken $SHOPIFY_STORE_TOKEN' $infoPlistPath"
                            sh "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :CFBundleIdentifier $BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER' $infoPlistPath"

                            // Use the Fastlane username and password directly
                            sh 'bundle exec fastlane beta'

                            // Additional steps or cleanup as needed
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Fastlane script:

```
default_platform(:ios)
```

platform :ios do
desc "Description of what the lane does"
lane :beta do
xcode_select("/Applications/Xcode.app")

bundle_identifier = sh("ruby get_bundle_identifier.rb", log: true).strip

```
puts "Fetched bundle identifier: #{bundle_identifier}"

latest_build_number = latest_testflight_build_number(
  app_identifier: bundle_identifier
)
UI.message("Latest TestFlight Build Number: #{latest_build_number}")

increment_build_number(
  build_number: latest_build_number + 1
)

match(
  type: "appstore",
  app_identifier: bundle_identifier,
  git_url: “gitURL"
)

app_store_connect_api_key(
  key_id: "key_id",
  issuer_id: "issuer_id",
  key_filepath: "key_filepath",
  duration: 1200,
  in_house: false
)
```

gym(
scheme: "beCo-Store",
export_options: {
method: "app-store",
provisioningProfiles: {
bundle_identifier => "match AppStore #{bundle_identifier}"
},
signingCertificate: "iPhone Distribution"
}
)

```
sync_code_signing(
  type: "appstore",
  git_url: "git_url",
  app_identifier: bundle_identifier
)

upload_to_testflight(
skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true, # Add this to skip waiting
wait_processing_interval: 30, # Increase the interval
app_platform: 'ios'
)
```

end
end

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your current Jenkins and Fastlane scripts?

Comment: Hello @Aaron Brager, I've edited the question to add the Jenkinsfile and the fastlane script. Let me know of you need more information.